# Dual boot windows 10 and Vivid Vervet keyboard backlight stopped working again [samsung np900x3c]

Tags: 15.04, uefi, laptop, keyboard-backlight

TL;DR: dual boot win10 and ubuntu 15.04 - keyboard backlight on my samsung np900x3c laptop not working.

I've been dual booting Utopic Unicorn along with windows 8 with great success for a long time. I've installed Utopic in CSM OS mode so basically when Safe Booting UEFI I saw only windows and to go to Utopic I went into the BIOS settings, changed the mode and Ubuntu it was.

Now I've finally decided to upgrade to Windows 10 and upon doing so my CSM OS boot stopped working. Grub failure emergency mode. Since I didn't have anything important there I thought, why not go 15.04 on the Ubuntu side. So I've created my usb stick with LiLi and went on installing.

The first thing I noticed was that in CSM OS mode booting from the stick does not work "No Operating System Found". So I've installed under UEFI mode (safe boot off) and now I have an ambivalent situation:

1. I can boot to both systems without the BIOS fuss. (yay!)
2. My keyboard backlight stopped working again. (boo!)

I say again because version 14.10 was the one that made the keyboard backlight work in the first place. Now, whatever backlight state is set when turning off windows persists during the whole Ubuntu session. The buttons are working in the sense that they make the backlight hover appear but don't change the setting.